# Install nginx + passenger on CentOS which was installed apache + passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, nginx, centos, passenger

I'm finding about `server`, i built a website which i used `Ruby on Rails` and i want to deploy it on server `CentOS 7`.

I'm going to install new `webserver` `Nginx + Passenger` on `CentOS 7`.

But in this `server` was installed `Apache + Passenger`.

I wonder that are there any problems with my website if i install `Nginx + Passenger` and **STOP** service `Apache + Passenger` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There won't be any problem if you STOP using `Apache + Passenger` service. Instead you can install and use `Nginx + Passenger` on CentOS7. You follow this in [nginx + passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install/oss/trusty/)